# Infinite loop when trying to back fill existing documents Firebase extension and Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I'm trying to create a simple Firebase extension. I enabled the option to backfill existing users. This means that when someone installs the extension, I will add a ranking (number) in the real-time database. The problem arrives when the number of users is large and I need to perform long-running tasks. I read the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/publishers/lifecycle-events#long-running) and here is what I have tried:

```
exports.doBackfillExistingDocuments = tasks
    .taskQueue()
    .onDispatch(async (data) => {
      const offset = data["offset"] !== undefined ? data["offset"] : 0;

      const snapshot = await getFirestore()
          .collection("users")
          .limit(DOCS_PER_BACKFILL)
          .get();

      const processed = await Promise.allSettled(
          snapshot.docs.map(async (doc) => {
            const ref = getDatabase().ref().child("rankings").child(doc.id);
            await ref.set(0);
          }),
      );

      if (processed.length == DOCS_PER_BACKFILL) {
        const queue = getFunctions().taskQueue(
            "doBackfillExistingDocuments",
            process.env.EXT_INSTANCE_ID,
        );
        await queue.enqueue({
          offset: offset + DOCS_PER_BACKFILL,
        });
      } else {
        getExtensions().runtime()
            .setProcessingState(
                "PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
                "Backfill complete.",
            );
      }
    });
```

I'm a newbie in JavaScript, but per my understanding this code should get the number of documents per back fill, which is 20 and then continue until it finishes to back fill all documents. The problem arrives when I deploy the extension. The first 20 documents are added to the real-time database and then the `doBackfillExistingDocuments` is called over and over again, like in an infinite loop. What exactly can cause that? Please help me, because I had thousands of invocations in a very short time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps be missing the offset in your snapshot query.

```
const snapshot = await admin
  .firestore()
  .collection(process.env.COLLECTION_PATH)
  .offset(offset)
  .limit(DOCS_PER_BACKFILL)
  .get();
```

A complete example can found in the Firestore Translate extension.

source: https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/next/firestore-translate-text/functions/src/index.ts

Comment: Hey Derren. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Let me try and get back to you.

Comment: I cannot see any `offset()` function inside [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) class not inside the [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Query) class. I found a function called startAt, but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: The reference you have linked is the client SDK. Offset is only a feature in the server based sdks. Please see https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html. Note the reference at the top of the file references, import * as admin from "firebase-admin". That should provide the offset feature!